# Create one-to-many and a many-to-one relationship - SQLite & Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, .net-core

I am  looking for help and a clear answer with example in the most simple way possible if you can on how to create the following:

- Patient has many appointments (one to many)
- A doctor can have many appointments (one to many)
- Patient can have many attendances (one to many)
- A doctor can have many attendances (one to many)
- The patient will have attendance notes that the doctor will access and create.

I am thinking of scrapping the attendance bit and just simply have the patient to appointments and appointments to doctor.

How do I create the patient to appointments (selecting the doctor as well) and then appointments to doctor?

My example:

```
public class Patient 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Full name { get; set; }

    public IList<Appointment> Appointments { get; set;} = new List<appointment>();
}

public class Appointment 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public int Patient ID { get; set; }
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
 }
```

Does anyone know what I need to include in the `Appointment` class to make sure it allows me to enter in a doctor or select the doctor that will be created with the appointment?

Then what do I need to do to allow a doctor class to interact with the `Appointment` class and attendance class.

To keep it simple, even only just how the appointments can link with a specific doctor and the doctor links to the Appointment class, so I can filter through later in in the doctor view and see what dates and his or her name selected if that makes sense?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#indirect-many-to-many-relationships Just replace `Post` with `Patient`, `PostTag` with `Appointment` etc.

Comment: @Jeremy Lakeman do I replace tag with doctor then and that gives me the 3 links I need for patient to Appointment and doctor to Appointment? How do I got about making sure that the doctor is selected in the Appointment class for later on so the patient can book s specific time with the specific doctor if that makes sense?

Comment: You'll need to populate all the appointment properties before saving. Unless the FK is nullable.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, do you mean popular as add in all the details that I need? Also, do I replace tag with doctor and that created my relationships between all three tables?

Comment: You asked for an example with three tables, the above link was the quickest I could find. Now it's your job to understand it and work out how to adapt the example to your needs.